# Statement problems

Tags: logic

It was a hot day and four couples drank together 44 bottles of cold drink. Anita had 2, Biva 3, Chanchala 4 and Dipti 5 bottles. Mr. Pannikar drank just as many bottles as his wife, but each of the other men drank more than his wife- Mr.Dube twice, Mr.Narayan three times and Mr.Rao four times as many bottles. Then only one statement is correct:

1). Mrs. Pannikar is Chanchala
2). Anita's husband had 8 bottles
3). Mr.Narayan had 12 bottles
4). Mrs.Rao is Dipti

I tried every possible thing but still I am not able to get even close to the answer.

Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

2). is correct.

Marriages:

Anita - Mr. Rao

Biva - Mr. Narayan

Chanchala - Mr. Dube

Dipti - Mr. Pannikar

All other ways make too many bottles.

Therefore Anita drank 2 bottles, and her husband, Mr. Rao, drank 4x as much or 8 bottles.

Comment: Hey I guessed that to be the answer........but if u total up everything you won't get 44........ now how is that possible??

Comment: Are you sure? Can you show me the math? I will help you.

Comment: oh i am so sorry........i was not adding the bottles drank by the wives..........my bad! Thanks for ur help.......i appreciate it! @Eliseo Palit-ang

Comment: Your welcome. Was I right?

Comment: oh my goodness.......do u still have a doubt? Of course you are right!

Comment: I don't think that makes sense.